# CodeIgniter call function within the same class

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to do this code in my CodeIgniter application :

```
<?php
  class Inventory extends Controller {

    function current_stock()
    {
      //do something
    }

    function add_stock()
    {
      //do something-else
      ****then do function current_stock()*****

    }

  }
```

How do I execute another function from within a second one?
The approach outlined [here](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY) (about extending controllers) is something of an overkill for me.

Am I missing a much easier way?

Answer (score 107):

OK, I agree this is a MAJOR goof-up; comes from lack of OOP understanding;

```
<?php
class Inventory extends Controller {
    function current_stock() {
        //do something
    }

    function add_stock() {
        //do something-else
        $this->current_stock();
        // and we called the other method here!
    }
}
```

Just that I didn"t expect it to be so easy

Comment: $this, o i a java guy with direct calls.. :\

Answer (score 8):

Just use `$this->your_function_name();`

Answer (score 4):

Only $this->nameFunction(); 
example

```
<?php 

class Hello extends CI_Controller{

 public function index(){
  $this->hello();
 }
public function hello(){
  return "hello world";
 }
}
```