# How to call another Codeigniter Class/function from other Codeigniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, class

I want to call A (Codeigniter) login Class and it functions from B Codeigniter. Anyone can explain and share idea how can do this. Thanks

Comment: This may help you http://www.techsirius.com/2013/01/load-controller-within-another.html

Comment: Thanks Jenz for your reply but I want to call class from another codeigniter (directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is similar to:

[How to load a controller from another controller in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165895/how-to-load-a-controller-from-another-controller-in-codeigniter)

or [Codeigniter call function within same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048924/codeigniter-call-function-within-same-class)

Try this, you will get solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
  public function is_logged()
  {}
}

class Home_Controller extends MY_Controller {
    public function show_home()
    {
         if (!$this->is_logged()) {
           return false;
         }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I want to call class from another codeigniter (directory) example: Call A codeignitor (login) class from B Codeigntor directory (test) class