# How to pass variables from 1 method to another inside controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, methods

i Want to get all these variables at one place so that i can add them into DB using a model. 
Thank you in advance.

```
          public function web_login()
    {
            $data['user'] = array();

            if ($this->facebook->is_authenticated())
            {

                $user = $this->facebook->request('get', '/me?fields=id,name,email');
                if (!isset($user['error']))
                {
                    $data['user'] = $user; // ***WANNA PASS THIS VARIABLE FROM HERE***

                    $this->load->view('user/header');
                    $this->load->view('user/fbpass');
                    $this->load->view('user/footer');

            }
            else {
                $this->load->view('user/register');
            }
        }
}
```

SECOND METHOD________________________________________________

```
                public function getpass(){
                $this->load->model('user_model', 'auth');
                $this->load->view('user/header');
                $this->load->library('form_validation');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('passwordagain', 'Password Confirmation', 'required|matches[password]');

                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                {
                        $this->load->view('user/fbpass');
                }
                else  
                {
                        $password=$this->input->post('password');

                       ***//WANNA GET THAT VARIABLE HERE***
                }            

        }
```

Comment: Depends. How are the 2 methods linked?

Comment: these are inside same controller

Comment: use `session` to store that data & fetch it from `session`

Comment: you can define class variable , then assign value to it in function you need to get value from $this->variable_name = 'value' , then call it in another function $this->variable_name

Comment: You can use global variables

Comment: can i get a piece of code? I am newbee

Comment: If these are never run in the same request, then it would seem @M.Hemant is correct suggesting sessions. Or other storage.

Comment: second method triggers by first

Comment: if a second method trigger by first then please update in your code and just pass the `$user` as a parameter in the second method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter call function within the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048924/codeigniter-call-function-within-the-same-class)

Answer (score 0):

```
class ClassName{
    public $var;
    function one(){
        $this->var = 'value';
    }

    function two(){
        return $this->var; // if you call function one then call function two you will get value
    }
}
```

but if you need to call them not the same time you can use session

```
$_SESSION['var'] = 'value';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class TestClass extends Controller {
    function test_mehtod($param) {
        //do something
       echo $param."<br>";
       echo "hi, you are in same controller";
    }

    function test_mehtod2() {
        //do something-else
        $this->test_mehtod("param value");
        // and we called the other method here!
    }
}
```